# Is there a shorthand for [:not] Pseudo class?

Tags: css

I was wondering if there is a shorthand for CSS pseudo selectors, since I have 4 repeated [:not] selectors.

```
div > h3 ~ div:nth-child(5):not(.no-need-2 > div):not(.no-need > div):not(p
    ~ div):not(.no-need)
```

Comment: Does the title *really* match the question well?

Comment: You can use a comma to separate multiple selectors in a single `:not`.

Comment: In my opinion the problem here isn't the CSS selector, but a bad choice on how the HTML  and classes are structured. Can you change the HTML? I was considering writing a proper answer, but if you can't change the HTML, it won't be worth it :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The title asks a very general question which I am not sure how to interpret so this answer sticks to the specific situation with the :not pseudo class.

See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not)

> The :not() pseudo-class requires a comma-separated list of one or more selectors as its argument. The list must not contain another negation selector or a pseudo-element.

For the selector given in the question therefore you could use

```
div > h3 ~ div:nth-child(5):not(.no-need-2 > div, .no-need > div, p ~ div, .no-need)
```

Most common browsers now support this list format but check https://caniuse.com/?search=not